# How to edit Inline keyboard after click?

Tags: telegram-bot

I use [botman](https://botman.io/)

Need to change the keyboard after clicking.
An example of implementation is in @shopbot (Telegram) after entering the command `/invoice`

How I tried to do:

```
$keyboard = Keyboard::create()->type( Keyboard::TYPE_INLINE )
        ->oneTimeKeyboard(false)
        ->addRow( KeyboardButton::create("My inline button")->callbackData('first_inline'),
            KeyboardButton::create("My inline button2")->callbackData('second_inline'))
        ->toArray();

    $changedKb = Keyboard::create()->type( Keyboard::TYPE_INLINE )
        ->oneTimeKeyboard(false)
        ->addRow( KeyboardButton::create("Changed")->callbackData('first_inline'),
            KeyboardButton::create("Changed2")->callbackData('second_inline'))
        ->toArray();

    return $this->ask('Test to inline', function (Answer $answer) use ($changedKb) {
        $this->bot->sendRequest('editMessageReplyMarkup',
            [
                'message_id' => $answer->getMessage()->getPayload()['message_id']
            ] + $changedKb, $answer->getMessage());
    }, $keyboard);
```

Using editMessageReplyMarkup, I did not succeed, after clicking on the button, the text changes, but the button disappears immediately

Maybe someone has a solution, not necessarily made through a botman

Answer (score 0):

There is a method on TelegramDriver class, that removes the keyboard, you can change it

```
/**
 * This hide the inline keyboard, if is an interactive message.
 */
public function messagesHandled()
{
    $callback = $this->payload->get('callback_query');
    $hideInlineKeyboard = $this->config->get('hideInlineKeyboard', true);

    if ($callback !== null) {
        $callback['message']['chat']['id'];
        $this->removeInlineKeyboard($callback['message']['chat']['id'],
            $callback['message']['message_id']);
    }
}
```